# Saving OpenCV output in Motion JPEG format. Getting a "'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7" error

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I'd like to save video camera output in motion JPEG (MJPG) format. The below code,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
print("Unable to read camera feed")
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
frame_per_sec = int('10')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mjpeg',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),         (frame_per_sec), (frame_width,frame_height))
while(True):
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret == True:      
# Write the frame into the file 'output.mjpeg'
out.write(frame) 
# Display the resulting frame    
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
# Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break
else:
break 
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

While it will run, I am getting the following error(s),

```
[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x67706a6d/'mjpg' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mjpeg / raw MJPEG video'
```

What can I do to resolve these? I've tried changing the case, ('M','J','P','G' to 'm','j','p','g') with no success.
Appreciate any suggestions regarding resolving the above issue, as well as the GStreamer issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`.mjpeg` is not a valid suffix for any known container format.

I'm sure you didn't intend to write a *raw MJPG stream* without a container. That is *very very* rarely useful at all and requires expert knowledge.

You have two options:

1. use MJPG in a `.avi` container, because that's built into OpenCV and doesn't even require ffmpeg
2. use whatever ffmpeg understands, which would be a `.mpg` container, or `.mov` or `.mkv` or whatever else

Comment: Is this, "out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')," what you are suggesting?

Comment: yes, that is the first option