# OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363248/'H264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have tried Monai Video Segmentation, but I'm getting this error. How can I resolve it?

```
codecs = VideoFileDataset.get_available_codecs()

codec, ext = next(iter(codecs.items()))

print(codec, ext)
```

**Output:**

```
mp4v .mp4
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363248/'H264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 [/](https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/) MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x3234504d/'MP42' is not supported with codec id 15 and format 'mp4 [/](https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/) MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
[mp4 @ 0x3188dc700] Could not find tag for codec msmpeg4v2 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x47504a4d/'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mjpeg [/](https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/) raw MJPEG video'
```

I should get the output as inferred video but I am getting a video with full green color. How to resolve this error?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553092/saving-opencv-output-in-motion-jpeg-format-getting-a-mjpg-is-not-supported-w  among other posts that report the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving OpenCV output in Motion JPEG format. Getting a "'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553092/saving-opencv-output-in-motion-jpeg-format-getting-a-mjpg-is-not-supported-w)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.